# How to get the value of an attribute and display it on a Tmemo

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, c++builder, tinyxml, tmemo

I have an xml file that looks like this...

```
<fruits>
    <apple color="red"/>
    <orange color="orange"/>
    <banana color="yellow"/>
</fruits>
```

I would like to take the value of the attribute *color* for each element, and display it on to a memo. I know how to display the value of an element on to a memo but I can't seem to figure out how to do it for an attribute. Here is my code so far...

```c
TiXmlDocument XMLFile;
XMLFile.LoadFile("fruits.xml");

TiXmlHandle XMLFileHandle( &XMLFile );
TiXmlElement* root = XMLFile .FirstChildElement("fruits");

for(TiXmlElement* elem = root->FirstChildElement(); elem != NULL; elem = elem->NextSiblingElement())
{
    memoOverview->Lines->Add(elem->Attribute("val")->GetText());
}
```

I am using tinyxml for the parsing of the xml file, and I am doing this in C++ and C++ Builder.

Comment: The code does not get syntax highlighting automatically, because you have not included a tag which the Google Code Prettify recognises.  See [question 73082 on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).

You can specify the language of the code, by including a `<!-- language: cpp -->` tag before the code block.  See the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
TiXmlDocument XMLFile;
XMLFile.LoadFile("fruits.xml");

TiXmlHandle XMLFileHandle( &XMLFile );
TiXmlElement* root = XMLFile.FirstChildElement("fruits");

char stringBuffer[64];

for (TiXmlElement* elem = root->FirstChildElement(); elem != NULL; elem = elem->NextSiblingElement())
{
  if (strcmp(LastChildElement->Value(), "color") == 0)
  {
    strncpy(stringBuffer, LastChildElement->Attribute("color"), sizeof(stringBuffer));
  }

  memoOverview->Lines->Add( stringBuffer );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlElement.html), you need to replace `elem->Attribute("val")->GetText()` with `elem->Attribute("color")`:

```
memoOverview->Lines->Add(elem->Attribute("color"));
```

Comment: it was meant to be posted with Attribute("color"). i posted the question using an example i created off the bat but forgot to change that part of the code. and for w/e reason it still wasn't working. what i ended up doing was copying the attribute as a string, and adding it onto the memo using that string